# Could not find action or result

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, struts-action, action-mapping

I am getting:

> com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn Could not find action or result
>   There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/]. - [unknown location]

I am using a combination of RAD + WebSphere for development with the following code:

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
```

**web.xml:**

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class> 
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter 
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

I have read all blogs & tried everything mentioned on sites. It is an error because of some different reason what I am unable to find .

Comment: The reason you have a slash added to the URL by the web server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no configuration for action name `[]` and namespace `[/]`. This is a problem. To solve this you should add a configuration. Supposed you have an `index.jsp` file in the root folder. Using a actionless result you can redirect to this page.

```xml
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
   <action name=""><result>/index.jsp</result></action> 
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this one but getting the same error. At least Login page should open which is mentioned in web.xml . <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

Comment: And how would you like to open this page? First you should invoke the action then return a result, but web server won't allow you to do it if you use a `welcome-file-list` configuration.

Comment: Above suggested option is working fine but stuck anywhere. When I use Struts2 filter in web.xml, it doesn't load remaining web.xml or index.jsp. But if I remove that filter from web.xml, it loads index.jsp. Ideally it should load index.jsp(web.xml) first than call goes to struts.xml  .

Comment: No, this is not the scenario. index.jsp is already at it's own place & whole mapping is perfect . I have crossed check the structure through net .